# Опции изменения текста при выделении

Tags: flutter, textview, flutter-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно знать как сделать эту панель и выделить определенный текст, а потом отменить выделение. Как сделать меню опций редактирования стиля текста над клавиатурой: выделение поддчеркивание и т. д. . При выделении менял стиль выделенного и мог отменять выделения ,да  про Spaneble знаю. И еще чтобы выделение применялось к TextView